# how to group elements of a list in Python then do an operation on the grouped elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, grouping

I have a list like below:

```
A = [1 , 2 , a, b , 5 , d]
```

I want to skip the first two elements in the list, and then make a new list like below:

```
B = [ 1 , 2 , a + b, 5 + d ]
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 1
b = 2
d = 3

B = [*A[:2], *map(sum, (A[i: i + 2] for i in range(2, len(A), 2)))]

[1, 2, 3, 8]
```

Comment: Why not just add the two element rather than summing lists which are constantly of length `2`?

Comment: you can do that as well, comes down to coding style wouldn't you say

Comment: maybe, I think it is neater to not use map though...

Comment: depends on the situation, using higher order functions has benefits depending on size of the data

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list-comprehension and concatenation.

```
A = [1, 2, a, b, 5, d]
B = A[:2] + [A[i]+A[i+1] for i in range(2, len(A), 2)]
```

Which, for `a,b,d = 100,200,400`, gives:

```
[1, 2, 300, 405]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are asking

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = list()
B.append(A[0])
B.append(A[1])
ii = 2
while ii < len(A)-1:
    B.append(A[ii] + A[ii+1])
    ii += 2
print B
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 7, 11]
```

Of course this assumes that `A` has an even number of elements, if `A` is odd the last element will be neglected.